# How to make each hadoop mapper to get a file pair i.e. a whole input file (.csv) and a whole meta data file (.json)

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I have hundreds to thousands of input files (.csv) and meta data files (.json) in the same folder say. $HDFS_ROOT/inputFolder

// Input data .csv files

input_1.csv, input_2.csv..input_N.csv

// Input meta data .json files

input_1.json, input_2.json..input_N.json

Can some one give me tips on how to make each mapper to get a file pair i.e. a whole input file (.csv) and its meta data file (.json).

NOTE: input_i.csv and input_i.json should go to the same mapper so that both the input and its meta data will be meaningful to validate.

What I tried:
I tried using WholeFileInputFormat and WholeFileRecordReader extending from FileInputFormat and RecordReader respectively. This would suffice for .csv files only. Also, I placed the .json files in to distributed cache to be accessible by the mapper. Its not a good solution.

Comment: What did you try ? This is not a coding service where others code for you.

Comment: Chill. I tried using WholeFileInputFormat and WholeFileRecordReader extending from FileInputFormat and RecordReader respectively. This would suffice for .csv files only. Also, I placed the .json files in to distributed cache. Its not a good solution.

Comment: Why not leave this up to the reducer? Use MultipleInputs to get your CSV and JSON data into different mappers, then join them in the reduce stage. That would be the expected way to deal with this issue. I presume that wouldn't be great for you because you want to do a further join, so maybe this job would be better dealt with outside of MapReduce? Cascading would let you do map -> reduce -> reduce.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. Just saw an example for MultipleInputs as well here: http://www.lichun.cc/blog/2012/05/hadoop-multipleinputs-usage/

Correct me if I am understanding your MR based thoughts. Each Mapper would emit the key as say "input_i" and the corresponding (whole) data of .csv and .json as Text and at reducer, we would get key "input_i" and values of iterable<Text>. Now, reducer can do validation, transformation etc. or just emit the key "input_i" and the value as .json data + .csv data. The next stage of MR would now have access to both .json + .csv data for processing.

Comment: Some of the problems I see is: Order of Text values at reducer can be different i.e. first value could be the Text consisting of .csv data or .json data. Also, what if the file size of .csv is greater than 64MB or 128MB. Then the values could be > 2. How do we determine whether the value in the iterable<Text> is .csv data or .json data.

Comment: I was thinking of the thought (not sure if this is feasible) where each mapper would get the path of the .csv and the associated .json file. Mapper now has both the .csv and .json file paths, so that it can read the file from hdfs and process based on the business logic of validation, transformation and etc. but not sure, how to accomplish this as I haven't seen an example on those lines.

( I haven't worked on cascading or scala/scalding so was exploring the java MR solution. )

Answer (score 1):

The key to solving this problem without using costly Reducer is InputSplits. Each InputFormat has method **getSplits**, a single split is an input for a single Mapper, there are as many Mappers as there are InputSplits. 
In the mapper it is possible to gain access to the instance of the InputSplit:

```
@Override
protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
     System.out.println("TRACE 1 " + context.getConfiguration().getClass().getName());
     System.out.println("TRACE 2 " + context.getTaskAttemptID().toString());
     System.out.println("TRACE 3 " + context.getInputSplit().toString());

}
```

Based on this there are 3 approaches which I have used in the past:

1) **context.getInputSplit()** returns an instance of **FileSplit**, which has **Path getPath()** method. But you have to watch out for **CombineFileSplit** and **TaggedInputSplit** which could wrap around the **FileSplit**. With **CombineFileSplit** if you do not override the default behaviour around **CombineFileInputFormat.pools**, than you risk to mix records with different structures in the same Mapper without being able to distinguish them;

2) A simpler approach would be use **context.getInputSplit().toString()**, returned string will contain the path that the **InputSplit** is attached to, works well with **MultipleInputs**, but not with **CombineFileInputFormat**. It is a little bit dirty as you are at the mercy of the **toString()** methods, would not recommend it for production system, but is good enough for quick prototypes;

3) To define your own implementation of a proxy **InputFormat** and **InputSplit**, similar to what MultipleInputs approach uses, it relies on **DelegatingInputFormat** which wraps around the **InputSplit** of the **InputFormat** that can read the data, but puts them inside of **TaggedInputSplit**, see the source code. In your case you can hide the metadata logic in the your own **InputFormat** and **InputSplits** and make Mappers free of knowing how to match file to the metadata. Also you can directly associate input paths to metadata without relying on the naming conventions. This approach is well suited for production systems.